# How can I edit a NSCFDictionary obtained with json query?

Tags: ios, json

I have a query in my app that return an NSCFDictionary object with the format :
object = { (values...) };  This is the json object:

```
 [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:url completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err)
```

And I need edit this. How can convert this to String for make the changes and then convert to NSCFDictionary again??

Thanks!

Comment: or you can do `[myDict mutableCopy]` to get a NSMutableDictionary and edit values directly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything in JSONModel's documentation indicating how to create a NSMutableDictionary from the JSON you receive in the HTTP response. That would be the ideal way to handle this.
What you can do is this:

```
NSDictionary *immutableDict = (NSDictionary *)json;
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [immutableDict mutableCopy];
mutableDict[@"keyToChange"] = @"the new value";
```

Comment: But I want to change content, with mutableDict I can't change content.. I'm trying something like: NSArray * values =[mutableDict allValues];
                 for (id value in values) {
                     
                     NSLog(@"value =%@",value);
                 }     But when I add value into NSString And change this with appendString or similar method, I obtain a error __NSCFArray appendString:      Some idea??

Comment: You need to either replace the NSString value (with whatever your new, desired string is) or convert the NSString to NSMutableString and change it. All three of the types you're working with NSString, NSArray, and NSDicitionary have mutable variants.